# Some scripts (languages) are missing in my Character Map

Tags: language-support

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

In my character-map some scripts (Languages) are missing.

How can I get them? Is it possible to reinstall them?

For example,here there is no mathematics option:

[image: ims]

```
apt-cache policy gucharmap
gucharmap:
Installed: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu2
Candidate: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu2
Version table:
*** 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu2 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Just a guess but you maybe need to install specialised fonts? `apt-cache search math | grep font` gives a list you may want to look at. `ttf-bitstream-vera` has "a selection of mathematical and other symbols". Hope this helps. By the way, I see what you see and I haven't installed `Microsoft TrueType core` fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the view from <kbd>By Script</kbd> to <kbd>By Unicode Block</kbd> via the menu entry <kbd>View</kbd>.

After that is an entry <kbd>Mathematical Operators</kbd> in the left pane:

[image]

---

Or Tamil

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-tamil-fonts
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without switching, most of the math symbols are in the "Common" section.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the font and script issues for me.

`sudo apt install fonts-noto`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1111736/319946)